# Cant import keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I ran the following on my `Anaconda` command prompt for `python 3.6`:

```
pip install keras
```

Next, typing the following on Spyder:

```
import keras
```

The above gives me an error:

> No module named 'tensorflow'

Tring to do `pip install tensorflow` on the `Anaconda` command prompt gives me the follwing error:

> No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

To install a module into anaconda, use

```
$ conda install tensorflow
```

The command that you ran

```
$ pip install tensorflow
```

will not install it inside the anaconda virtualenv for python.
If you try

```
$ python
>>> import keras
```

This will work after pip install tensorflow. However, use conda package manager to install modules to anaconda.